# How can i show details "on click" of a polyline Google Maps API V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Directions API to request a direction route between 2 points.I parsed the "overview polyline" tag and decoded it to a list of LatLng objects.I have drawn the polyline by adding it to the GoogleMap object. Polyline is shown ok till now.

Now i want to be able to click on this polyline and show details like distance and time for every point of the polyline is clicked.

How could i do this?? 
I suppose ill need a click listener but i couldnt find anything working. Can u help me please??

(I need a Java solution NOT javascript and I need only for maps V2)

thx

Comment: Seems to be duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416457/clickable-polylines-google-maps-api-android.